# Fragmented listview view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

Tags: android, listview, row

I have a Fragmented Listview that gets populated from a string array.
What I am after is when I click on selected row it turns green and stays green.
with what I have sort of works as long you don't scroll. Soon as you scroll rows that have not been selected have had the backgrounds changed.
From what I understand this is due to the way the listview recycles its views.
I have spent many hours trying different ways to implemented away to stop this happening but I lack the knowledge on how to do this.

```
public class AreaListFragment extends ListFragment {

private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
private CentreDataContent mContent;
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

public interface Callbacks {
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

public AreaListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (mContent == null) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        mContent = new CentreDataContent(R.integer.UnknownID,
                                         res.getStringArray(R.array.undefinedArea),
                                         res.getStringArray(R.array.undefinedChecklist));

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CentreDataContent.CentreArea>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            CentreDataContent.AREAS));
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);      
    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    } 
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(CentreDataContent.AREAS.get(position).id.toString());

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick
            ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
            : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
```

}

I am very new to android and am trying to learn. so any help on this would be great
many thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to be doing is creating a background state drawable which changes based on the state of the row.

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

as you can see here when the state got to `activated` that specific drawable is shown

so when an item in your list is clicked all you have to do is

```
listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

and that will cause the root view in your layout to be set to activated and change the background.

Now you have to also manage your previous row checked by keeping track of it and turning off the activated state when a new one is pressed by doing

```
listview.setItemChecked(lastPosition, false);
```

you can of course just set your listview to [CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) and you shouldnt have to worry about managing the previous item clicked.

```
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: thx for the responce i have setup a list_selector.xml in  my drawables folder with the following code you gave. Also in my colors.xml setup the drawing list_pressed_holo as follows.
'<drawable name="list_pressed_holo">#00FF00</drawable>'
also added this line listview.
'android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"'
But not sure where in the code i put the other lines
'listview.setItemChecked(position, true);'
'listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);'

Comment: set item check goes in the onListItemClick and the other goes in your onCreate